# Change x and y properties of textStyle in react google charts

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

How can I change the x and y co-ordinates of text in react-google-charts?

```
vAxis: {
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#232323",
    marginRight: 10,
  },
},
hAxis: {
  textStyle: {
    slantedTextAngle: 90
  },
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the official google chart docs, they are quite helpful -> https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    legend: { position: "bottom" },
    colors: ["#01B8FF", "#EB6F33", "#03C895"],
    chartArea: { width: "40%", height: "70%" },
    isStacked: true,
    bar: {groupWidth: '30'},
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: "#232323",
      },
    },
};
This properties can be used to create a horizontal stacked chart.
```